# High CPU usage and load on simple tasks

Tags: debian, xorg, cpu-usage, amd

I know my dual-core `AMD Athlon 64 X2 5200` is not powerful at all, but the problem is that I see how it is at (usually) 20% of usage in idle, and that's not a problem to me, maybe it just can't do much more... However, I note how sometimes it's "powerful", but sometimes no. I don't know if that's package-related, kernel-related, or some services... But the point is that it takes to 80/100% quickly for the most simple tasks I could do. Yes, it happens with Firefox obviously, but taking 50/60% when browsing throug my files isn't normal.

I have noted this behavior is not normal because I have seen how it can do much more in the past or in some rare occasions, so **something makes me feel that there is an issue that cause my apps to use more cpu cycles than it should**, all apps, nor only ... Or as if my graphics card were not used.

I have never tested Windows or other systems than MX Linux 19.2, so I can't test it in deep, however, I had the MX default Linux Kernel 4.19, and I note a very little difference (to better) when using current.

A process is **ever** consuming more CPU resources than usual is Xorg. I don't know if that's normal because it's persistent, always between 5% and 15%. But as I have a graphics card, I don't know why xorg needs that space or if it's affected/it affecs other processes.

I need to at that this sacrifice my CPU a lot because it's always overheating, so in the night this effect is a bit mitigated.

Is this maybe happening because of some kernel patches or wrong libreries configuration?
**Please request whatever additional information you need.**

```
System:    Host: <filter> Kernel: 5.6.0-1-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.3.0 
           parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.6.0-1-amd64 root=UUID=<filter> ro splash 
           acpi_enforce_resources=lax zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lz4 zswap.max_pool_percent=20 zswap.zpool=z3fold 
           Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 tk: Gtk 3.24.5 info: xfce4-panel, vala-panel, plank wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM 1.26.0 
           Distro: MX-19.2_x64 patito feo February 15  2020 base: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: FOXCONN model: M61PMV v: FAB A1 serial: <filter> BIOS: Phoenix v: P02 date: 07/08/2008 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: AMD Athlon 64 X2 5200+ bits: 64 type: MCP arch: K8 rev.F+ family: F (15) 
           model-id: 6B (107) stepping: 2 microcode: N/A L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 svm bogomips: 10850 
           Speed: 2700 MHz min/max: 1000/2700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2700 2: 2700 
           Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected 
           Type: l1tf status: Not affected 
           Type: mds status: Not affected 
           Type: meltdown status: Not affected 
           Type: spec_store_bypass status: Not affected 
           Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
           Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full AMD retpoline, STIBP: disabled, RSB filling 
           Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GK107 [GeForce GT 640] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia v: 418.152.00 bus ID: 02:00.0 
           chip ID: 10de:0fc1 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa alternate: nv 
           resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GT 640/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.152.00 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: NVIDIA MCP61 High Definition Audio vendor: Foxconn driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:05.0 
           chip ID: 10de:03f0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GK107 HDMI Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 02:00.1 
           chip ID: 10de:0e1b 
           Device-3: Nam Tai E&E Products or OmniVision Sony Playstation Eye type: USB driver: ov534,snd-usb-audio 
           bus ID: 1-2:2 chip ID: 1415:2000 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.6.0-1-amd64 
Network:   Device-1: NVIDIA MCP61 Ethernet vendor: Foxconn type: network bridge driver: forcedeth v: kernel port: ec00 
           bus ID: 00:07.0 chip ID: 10de:03ef 
           IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 298.09 GiB used: 210.49 GiB (70.6%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Hitachi model: HDS721032CLA362 size: 298.09 GiB block size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B 
           speed: 3.0 Gb/s rotation: 7200 rpm serial: <filter> rev: A3EA temp: 36 C scheme: GPT 
Partition: ID-1: / raw size: 64.00 GiB size: 62.50 GiB (97.65%) used: 24.08 GiB (38.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3 
           ID-2: /home raw size: 226.07 GiB size: 221.52 GiB (97.99%) used: 186.12 GiB (84.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 1024.0 MiB used: 302.8 MiB (29.6%) fs: swap swappiness: 15 (default 60) 
           cache pressure: 100 (default) dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 83.0 C mobo: 42.0 C gpu: nvidia temp: 45 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 fan-2: 0 fan-3: 2528 gpu: nvidia fan: 10% 
           Voltages: 12v: N/A 5v: 2.93 3.3v: N/A vbat: 3.18 
Repos:     Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           1: deb https://typora.io/linux ./
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list 
           1: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mx.list 
           1: deb https://mirrors.evowise.com/mxlinux-packages/mx/repo/ buster non-free main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list 
           1: deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list 
           1: deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ buster main
Info:      Processes: 229 Uptime: 6h 03m Memory: 3.85 GiB used: 2.22 GiB (57.7%) Init: SysVinit v: 2.93 runlevel: 5 default: 5 
           Compilers: gcc: 8.3.0 alt: 8 clang: 7.0.1-8+deb10u2 Shell: quick-system-in running in: quick-system-in inxi: 3.0.36
```

[image]

Comment: Examples: Scrolling in Firefox sums around 30/40% usage, while a gif on the page could cause a 60/70% usage. With Firefox this problem is so hard.

Comment: Scrolling up and down in the whisker menu is also significative (+30/35%)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with cooling of this CPU and it is speedsteping to some lower MHz than usual?

Comment: It's a good highlight and something I have not thought... Could you add ways to measure the CPU MHz in real-time and in that way possibly get conclusions? — In my attached details, it's shown that my CPU has `Speed: 2700 MHz min/max: 1000/2700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2700 2: 2700` — Not evident thermal throttling here.

Comment: I'll let it stand for now, but yeah - this is closer to a comment than an answer.